# How to get script name inside function in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I have three scripts:

- My main script: script1.sh
- Script having function 'logger': script2.sh
- Script calling the function 'logger': script3.sh

Contents of my script:

script1.sh:

```
echo"This is script1"
source script2.sh
sh script3.sh
echo "End of script1"
```

script2.sh:

```
logger(){
 echo "The calling script name is $BASH_SOURCE"
}
```

script3.sh:

```
echo "Script3 start"
logger
echo "End of script3"
```

When I run `sh script1.sh`, I want the logger function to print

> script3.sh

because that is the script which is calling the function. But instead, it is printing

> script2.sh

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Pass the name of the script which is calling `logger` via a parameter?

Comment: In the beginning, I thought so. But I do not want to hardcode it.

Comment: this is unlikely. you did not show everything. in bash, functions are not exportable, therefore sourcing `script2` in `script1` won't make `logger` visible in `script3`. you must have done something in `script3`.

Comment: It wouldn't be hardcoding, simply pass `$0` as the argument when calling `logger`.

Comment: Is running `sh script1.sh` just prints `script2.sh`? Am sure it would have printed more. Post the full content

Comment: @SeanPianka, thanks. That should do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I commented, your scripts won't even do what you claimed it does:

> this is unlikely. you did not show everything. in bash, functions are not exportable, therefore sourcing script2 in script1 won't make logger visible in script3. you must have done something in script3.

Indeed, copying your code and run it locally indicates what's happening:

```
$ ./script1.sh 
++ echo 'This is script1'
This is script1
++ source script2.sh
++ sh script3.sh
+ echo Script3 start
Script3 start
+ log
script3.sh: 3: script3.sh: log: not found
+ echo End of script3
End of script3
++ echo 'End of script1'
End of script1
```

notice the command not found error, which is exactly what I thought.

---

In fact, if you check bash's manual properly, there is a proper way of achieving what you want exactly:

> BASH_SOURCE
>
> An array variable whose members are the source filenames where the corresponding shell function names in the FUNCNAME array  variable  are  defined.   The  shell  function
>   ${FUNCNAME[$i]} is defined in the file ${BASH_SOURCE[$i]} and called from ${BASH_SOURCE[$i+1]}.

read it carefully, it says function defined from `${BASH_SOURCE[$i]}` and called from `${BASH_SOURCE[$i+1]}`. In this case, `logger` resides in `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`, and the caller simply resides in `${BASH_SOURCE[1]}`.

therefore, change your `script2` to following shall work:

```
$ cat script2.sh 
log(){
 echo "The calling script name is ${BASH_SOURCE[1]}"
}
```

(except I changed the function name so that it does not collide with my other shell tool.)

---

demo:

```
$ ./script1.sh 
This is script1
Script3 start
The calling script name is ./script3.sh
End of script3
End of script1
```

indeed does the work.